# I will be leaving soon

Tags: syntax

It is almost the end of the day. So I want to say to my office mate that I will be leaving soon. Is it natural to say:

> そろそろ出ています。

or :

> そろそろ出発しています。

Comment: You should never have to say this because if you're a good Japanese employee, you'll be the last one at the office every night.  :D

Comment: Both of your sentences mean "they would have left now".

Comment: 「お先｛さき｝です！」「お先｛さき｝に失礼｛しつれい｝します！」「もう帰｛かえ｝るよ。」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately neither of your examples are very natural.

There are already a couple fixed expressions. 帰る (go home) or 失礼する (take my leave). You wouldn't use progressive forms for either. While in English you can say 'I'll be going home now', that doesn't work for Japanese. 'I go home now' is more natural.

出発する means to depart for somewhere, usually far off, that is not your home. 出る would indicate that you're going out, but you might be back.

「（もう）そろそろ失礼します」 or 「（もう）そろそろ帰ります」 would be appropriate.

Comment: What about 出かけるところです？

Comment: 出かける also implies imminent return, i.e. 'Stepping out for a while'. Which would be fine if you were just going to a meeting and coming right back: 出かけてくる

Comment: @ajsmart 出かける is okay for leaving home for school, work, (even) a (long) trip etc. and is also okay to use for leaving the office if you're coming back on the day. If you're stepping out for only a while and coming right back, 「 **ちょっと**出かけてきます。」とかね。

Comment: As far as V+ところ, you would use it for 'in the act of', or 'in the middle of'. If, at work, someone asks you to do something time-consuming for them, you could answer 「ちょっと帰るところですけど…」'I'm just leaving.' or 'I am already in the process of leaving'.

Comment: 「ちょっと帰るところですけど。」はちょっと・・・

Comment: 「ちょっと、今帰るところですけど...」の方がマシかな...

Comment: もうしかして、帰ってほしくないの？

Comment: Thank you. It's very interesting to learn the subtle differences among 出る, 帰る and 出発する. So, if I wanna say I'll be leaving for the restaurant soon, none of these 3 words would apply, correct? I am guessing that we'll simply use 行くas in もうそろそろレストランへ行きます。.

Comment: Exactly right. If the listener already knows that you will be leaving and to where you are headed, you can shorten it to a simple  そろそろ出発します or すぐ出発します。

Comment: Oh, 出発する is Ok for the restaurant situation? When you said that it applies to situation where one departs for somewhere usually far off, I had an impression that we'll only use 出発する if we are for example going out of town.

Comment: As there are already fixed expressions for ‘going home’ (帰る, etc.）, using 出発 would be an anomaly.  It would beg the question, ‘You’re not going home?, where are you going?’. Think of 出発 as ‘venture forth’ instead of ‘depart’ and it might make it easier. Your home is your principal base, so going home would not be venturing anywhere. You can, however, say it when you are headed off to school, work, etc.   ...cont.↓

Comment: Different verbs for movement carry different nuances depending on location. One of the definitions for 出発する is ‘set out from a place / set out on one’s journey’. 

Think of it as a large circle. In the very center you have your home (principal location). Near the center you have school, work, places you ‘venture to’ regularly. Then you have a nearby city farther out, and a foreign country even farther from the center. Any move in the direction away from center of the circle from your current location would be ‘venturing forth’. I hope this explanation is comprehensible.

Comment: Since we are on the subject, the difference between 帰る and 戻る is also location-specific.